# Accessing JSON Array using JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a table (Deltails) with two columns (Id+ Result) in SQL Server database,
where Id is the primary key and Result contains JSON object.

This Result column

```
[{"ID":"2023","Answer":"False","Reason":"Need attachment"}]
[{"ID":"1005","Answer":"TRUE","Reason":""}]
[{"ID":"1879","Answer":"TRUE","Reason":""}]
```

I'm trying to get from table Deltails, column Result, value Answer only.
For that, I wrote the following SQL query but I didn't get the result. Does anyone have an idea about to get JSON object value as the normal column value as a query result.

```
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE(X.value, '$.Answer') AS Name 
FROM Deltails
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Result) X
```

Thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include sample data as DDL+DML statements and expected results. For more information, check the [sql server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info).

Comment: Include something like: SELECT 'Example JSON Data' Results INTO #Deltails || Then show your query with the results and also what you expected.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: _For that, I wrote the following SQL query but I didn't get the result._ What result did you get? According to the posted information you should have gotten three rows with `False`, `TRUE` and `TRUE` in the `Name` column. What were you actually expecting?